# Removing the duplicates when setting up my database

Tags: csv, neo4j

I have a data in a csv file and I have a index row in each csv file for creating the relationships between the node. Some of the information repeats in the csv file so when i call a relationship instead of having the node of a actor appear and all the movie nodes he acts in connected to him, I have a bunch of seperate actor nodes individually connection to a movie node. Is there a way to tell neo4j that if 5 nodes are the same join them on the id so they will be represented by 1?

Answer (score 1):

You want to use MERGE on id. Example

```
Load csv .... as row
Merge (p:Person{Id: row.person})
Merge (m:Movie{id:row.movie})
ON CREATE set m.title = row.title
Merge (p)-[:acts]->(m)
```